# Python 3 unexpected behavior with isinstance method

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, subclass

I'm seeing some strange behavior with the isinstance method that I wouldn't expect. Can someone help me determine why this is occurring?

I have a module, sandbox.py, that I use to tinker with modules as I create them. I also have a binary tree class, binary_tree.py, and a BST class, bst.py, that inherits from the binary tree implementation and adds the constraint that the tree is sorted. I also have some utility methods that operate on trees, such as BFS, DFS, etc.

the problem is this: the class Bst (a BST node) is a subclass of Node (generic binary tree node). My utility methods have some checks to make sure their argument is an instance of Node or sub-type thereof:

```
def bfs(n: Node, process=None):
    . . . 
    assert isinstance(n, Node)
    # print for debugging
    print("util.py:", isinstance(n, Node))
    . . .
```

In the bfs method, the assertion passes with the following call, and then print prints:

```
tree = Bst("A")
bfs(tree, lambda n: print(n.data, end=' ')) # Ignore the implementation, just know this enters the method
util.py: True
```

As expected. However, in sandbox.py the same call prints False:

```
from trees.binary_tree import Node
from trees.util import *
from trees.bst import Bst

print("sandbox.py:", isinstance(Bst, Node))
sandbox.py: False
```

Why does isinstance return two different things when called from different locations even though the two arguments are of the same class?

If its relevant, my directory structure is this:

```
sandbox.py
trees/
    binary_tree.py
    bst.py
    util.py
```

Within bst.py Bst is defined as such:

```
Bst(Node):
    . . .
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you used `isinstance(Bst, Node)`. `Bst` is the *class*, not an instance. So your assertion that *even though the two arguments are of the same class?* is not true.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> tree = Bst("A")
> bfs(tree, ...)
>
> def bfs(n, ...):
>     isinstance(n, Node)
> ```

Here, `n` actually is an *instance* of `Bst`, a subclass of `Node`.

> ```
> from trees.bst import Bst
> isinstance(Bst, Node)
> ```

`Bst` is the class, not an instance of it, so `isinstance` is `False`.

Comment: Ah, dumb mistake. I should be using issubclass in this case.